# Preventing file update in java card

Tags: applet, javacard

I am working on a java card applet. In the applet, I am able to identify the file which is getting updated using a case in `processtoolkit()` using the below code. I am also able to identify the file id, but as per my requirement I want to know the file id before the file gets updated, and if possible I want to prevent the update for this particular file. Is there any way to identify file id before file update and prevent the file update? Because the below case is triggered after the file is updated. In short I want to prevent the file update for file `6F30`.

```java
public void processToolkit(byte bEvent)
{
 switch((byte)bEvent)
        {
          case EVENT_TRANSPARENT_FILE_UPDATE:
               EnvelopeHandler envHdlr = EnvelopeHandler.getTheHandler();

               ggsLenVar = (short)((short)(envHdlr.findAndCopyValue(TAG_FILE_LIST, fci,  (short) 0)) & (short)0x00FF);

               if(((fci[0x05] == 0x6F) && (fci[0x06] == 0x30)))
               {}
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get this. Is the file update managed from the applet? So the transparent file and file system are completely implemented in Java Card? If so, I don't get the question. If not, could you please include the full details about the runtime system of the card?

Comment: OK, that's the SIM toolkit I presume, I didn't much work on SIM's yet (and it shows :) )

Comment: Could you please still update your question to make this clear to future readers? Please indicate the runtime & API + version in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can not prevent file update,on applet you will only get the event when any transparent file updated via external entity.
Because file update goes to OS and via this event applet can only be notified that file is updated.
One thing you can do is re-update the file with desired content on receiving this event or you can set update condition to NEVER.

Comment: currently i am doing that only. but the thing is, 6F30 is can be updated through OTA. now as per my knowledge, there is a event to capture incoming sms pp. i.e. EVENT_FORMATTED_SMS_PP_ENV. but this even will only be triggered when the incoming smspp TAR value is same as our Application's TAR.if this is the case then i can parse it and handle the update part.but the difficulty i am facing is that my application TAR is different and the TAR value using which 6F30 is updated is different since its a standard file.i cannot give same TAR to my application and the applet using which 6F30 is updated.

Comment: in this case can you suggest what can be done. i.e. how can i make smspp event trigger in my application when 6F30 is updated using another TAR since its a standard file in SIM. i want my applet to trigger smspp event whenever 6f30 is updated. because when i use my TAR to updated 6F30 it does not get updated since its another applets file which used different TAR.

Comment: I think you should always get this event whenever file is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can not prevent file update via applet, But a workaround, you can take backup of `EF 6F30` at start up (`EVENT_FIRST_COMMAND_AFTER_RESET`) & can restore the value on this EVENT or as Anurag says can update with desired value.

Setting File Access to Never can cause some malfunction in behavior of phone, As GSM 11.11 says Update condition must be `CHV1`.

Good Luck !